# param and params usages in c++

Tags: c++

I am studying classes in c++ and i came across this snippet of code and i wondering what param was used for.

```
// vectors: overloading operators example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {};
    CVector (int,int);
    CVector operator + (CVector);
};

CVector::CVector (int a, int b) {
  x = a;
  y = b;
}

CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param) {
  CVector temp;
  temp.x = x + param.x;
  temp.y = y + param.y;
  return (temp);
}

int main () {
  CVector a (3,1);
  CVector b (1,2);
  CVector c;
  c = a + b;
  cout << c.x << "," << c.y;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the param in your overload as it is a member function. Use it only if operator + is a non member function.

Comment: @DumbCoder operator `+` has two operands not one!

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - I believe it is a unary + operator. And unary oprators don't require an argument if they are class members.

Comment: @DumbCoder And how did you come to this awesome conclusion? :-D

Comment: @DumbCoder: How the heck is that a unary operator? It _clearly_ performs addition between two operands. (If anything, unary op+ should be free.)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be @Tomalak Geret'kal  - I think I didn't get enough sleep .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Param is the right operand of the `+` operator.

Here is cleaner version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector ();
    CVector (int,int);
    CVector (const CVector&);
    CVector operator + (const CVector&) const;
};

CVector::CVector() : x(0), y(0) {}
CVector::CVector(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
CVector::CVector(const CVector& v) : x(v.x), y(v.y) {}

CVector CVector::operator+ (const CVector& param) const {
  CVector temp(*this);
  temp.x += param.x;
  temp.y += param.y;
  return (temp);
}

int main () {
  CVector a (3,1);
  CVector b (1,2);
  CVector c;
  c = a + b;
  cout << c.x << "," << c.y;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your declarations and definitions don't match. +1 [in advance of your imminent edit] for the good re-write.

Comment: They do now :) Thx, I completely skipped that.

Answer (score 2):

`Param` is just an identifier designating the right-hand operand ov the overloaded + operator. Instead of it you could use any other identifier.

```
CVector a, b;
a+b; //a is the object on which you call +, b is the param
```

Comment: And as such, an example other implementation could be: `CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector rhs) const { return CVector(x+rhs.x,y+rhs.y); }`